# How to set background color to the column using CSS?

Tags: html, css

There is a table. How to set specific background color for the last column using CSS? I need to do it without appending any classes or *style* attribute to TD elements and without using javascript.

Comment: That would exclude `id`s too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `<col>` tag in HTML. `<col>` can define specific attributes for certain columns.

```
<col/>
<col/>
<col style='width:500px; background:red;' id='says_col'/>
```

Would make the width of the third column 500px and the background red. These are very useful because they can be used to get to other things on specific columns. Here are some resources you might find useful.

http://www.boogiejack.com/html/html-col-tag.html

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

Comment: interesting, but I don't think it's an efficient way to build code, specially inline CSS

Comment: I agree here, everytime you add a column you will have to add a col tag?

Answer (score 12):

In css:

```
td { background: blue; }
td:last-child { background: red; }
```

These are called pseudo classes

You can get more info at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could use the last-child selector, but be warned that IE probably won't like this.

It'd go something like this:

```
#myTable tr td:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The server-side technology usually helps for this, by adding a "last" class to the last `td` element. Then, all you need is :

```
td.last {
    background: /* bleh */;
}
```

The `col` solutions sounds fun, even though I've never used it.